# Inserting two or more arrays into a "Final Array"?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    //header code to define as json and if $_GET statement...

    $JSONArrayA[$variableA] = array('id' => $idA, 'test' => $testVariableA);

    $JSONArrayB[$variableB] = array('id' => $idB, 'test' => $testVariableB);

    //current code resulting in ["ArrayArray"]
    $FinalJSONArray[] = $JSONArrayA . $JSONArrayB;

    echo json_encode($FinalJSONArray);
?>
```

My question:  How do I make the array contain two or more arrays? Any help appreciated.

Comment: That not the only help you need .... you also also have improve use of simple quotes `'` .. [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to see how to merge arrays

Comment: Haha, sorry, I was typing quite quickley.  I'll edit now.

Comment: `array_merge` for merging arrays

Comment: Ummm...what do you mean by `$JSONArrayA . $JSONArrayB`, exactly?

Comment: What exactly is your "final array" supposed to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $FinalJSONArray[] = $JSONArrayA;
 $FinalJSONArray[] = $JSONArrayB;
```

This will reult in 2 sub arrays. If you want them merged use:

```
 $FinalJSONArray[] = $JSONArrayA+$JSONArrayB;
```

"+" with two arrays unions them (see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

**[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

```
$FinalJSONArray = array_merge($JSONArrayA, $JSONArrayB);
```

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.

If you want to instead return an array **containing** the other two arrays themselves, 
use

```
 $FinalJSONArray = array($JSONArrayA, $JSONArrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want your JSON to look like

```
$FinalJSONArray = array($JSONArrayA,$JSONArrayB);
```